# Javascript function modular approach init variable issue

Tags: javascript, initialization, global, revealing-module-pattern

I have a modular libray javascript file where I am exposing two functions

1. init to initalise variables from my main.html file.
2. execValidation function to run based on those three variables collections initialised through main file.

For example:

```
var libraryModule = (function () {
  var arVals = {};
  var webFormData = {};
  var rules = [];

  function init(arVals, webFormData, rules) {
  //init all variables to global variables to use in execute Validations
    this.arVals = arVals;
    this.webFormData = webFormData;
    this.rules = rules;
  }

  //only passing RuleID, but it has dependencies of other variables, which I 
  //do not want to pass here
  function execValidation(ruleID) {
    //debugger;
    //Load arVals, webFormData and Rules from init
    var webFormData = this.webFormData;

    var arVals = this.arVals;
    var arVal = arVals[ruleID];

    var rules = this.rules;
    var rule = rules[ruleID]

    console.log(arVal);
    console.log(webFormData);
    console.log(rules);

  }

 return {
    execValidation: execValidation,
    init : init
 }
})(); // IIFE function
```

In My html file, I am calling like this

```
 var arVals = {};
    //calling json file using call back
    ruleConfigModule.init(function (data) {
        arVals = data;

    });

//passing the arVals, webFormData and rules collection to init
libraryModule.init(arVals, webFormData, rules);

Only passing the ruleID
var result = libraryModule.execValidation("Rule1");
```

I only want to pass one variable which is RuleID from execValidation function, but the init function should setup those variables inside the js library itself. Please can anyone help, as it does not work or help to re-organise it.

JSON calling method to populate arVals

```
var ruleConfigModule = (function () {

function init(callback) {
    loadJSON(function (json) {
        callback(json);
    });
}
// Let's hide this function

function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'http://localhost/test/config.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
        }
    };
    xobj.send();
}

return {
    //loadJSON: loadJSON,
    init: init
}
```

})();

> Updated: 
>   Blockquote
>   How do I ensure that arVals populated before the init method gets called?

Comment: this is not standard class, or prototype approach

Comment: This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0tvq7n41/ Can you tell us what the exact problem is? How does it "not work" (which is a useless problem description)?

Comment: I think I found one problem, this arVals is coming from json file , which is a call back function defined in the in my html file and it does not populate the arVals.

ruleConfigModule.init(function (data) {
                 arVals = data;
        });

How do i ensure, the arVals is populated before it gets passed

Comment: I have just updated my initial code, Chris G, you are right, sorry, the code works. it was the arVals which does not populate which is a json call. I have updated my code, please if anyone can respond? How do I ensure, that the variables gets filled first or the right approach ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function LibraryModule() {
  var arVals = {};
  var webFormData = {};
  var rules = [];
}

LibraryModule.prototype.init = function init(arVals, webFormData, rules) {
  //init all variables to global variables to use in execute Validations
  this.arVals = arVals;
  this.webFormData = webFormData;
  this.rules = rules;
}

LibraryModule.prototype.execValidation = function execValidation(ruleID) {
  //debugger;
  //Load arVals, webFormData and Rules from init
  var webFormData = this.webFormData;

  var arVals = this.arVals;
  var arVal = arVals[ruleID];

  var rules = this.rules;
  var rule = rules[ruleID]

  console.log(arVal);
  console.log(webFormData);
  console.log(rules);

  return rules;

}


let libraryModule = new LibraryModule();

libraryModule.init({
  rule: 'TEST'
}, {
  rule: 'TEST'
}, {
  rule: 'TEST'
})
var result = libraryModule.execValidation("rule");
console.log(result);
```